# PHP File upload wrong type

Tags: php, file, file-upload

When I upload a file in PHP I am getting the wrong type for xlsx files.

It is telling me the type is a file name

```
Array ( 
    [name] => report.xlsx 
    [type] => /folder/files/report/april_2013.xlsx 
    [tmp_name] => E:\path\to\temp\folder\phpCD1B.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 12433
)
```

Any ideas?

Hi

The code I am using is

view/display file

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="update_comp.php" name="myform2">
<label>Upload Files ( PDF,CSV or EXCEL only ) </label>
<input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

File update_comp.php

```
include ("filesFunctions.php"); 
if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
            $file = $_FILES["file"];
print_r($file);exit;
            $upload = new filesFunctions();
            $id = $upload->uploadFiles($file,'dairy');        

        }
```

the print_r() statement prints

```
Array (
    [name] => report.xlsx
    [type] => /folder/files/report/april_2013.xlsx
    [tmp_name] => E:\folder\to\temp\php5ACD.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 12433
)
```

Please note this only happens to xlsx files all other files work fine

Comment: Where does it get `april_2013` from, if the report is called `report.xlsx`?

Comment: Where did you get this array?

Comment: You don't provide much information, do you? File type information is provided by the browser so the first obvious troubleshooting step is to fire your browser's debugger tools and inspect the POST data it sends. If that's the source of the string, you can forget about PHP. Otherwise, you should **edit** the question and post the code you use to produce that output.

Comment: If this data is for real, something is very wrong. Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: ..even more weird is how (if the data is for real) that `tmp_name` is a windows path, yet `type` is a linux path.

Comment: Hi

The code I am using is
view/display file
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="update_comp.php" name="myform2"><label>Upload Files ( PDF,CSV or EXCEL only ) </label><input type="file" name="file</form>
File update_comp.php
include ("filesFunctions.php");if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
$file = $_FILES["file"];
print_r($file);}
print_r() statement prints
Array ( [name] => report.xlsx [type] => /folder/files/trendreport/april_2013.xlsx [tmp_name] => C:\folder\to\temp\php5ACD.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 12433 ) 
Please note only happens to xlsx files all other files work fine

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if Stack Overflow has secretly banned me and my comments are only visible to me... :(

Comment: @ Alvaro G Vicario, I have read your post and edited the question giving you the code I used to give the output.

Comment: @All - I am thinking is there a place in IIS6-7 / PHP where I may have hold it that this "/folder/files/report/april_2013.xlsx" if an file type. for XLSX files?

Answer (score 2):

The `type` key provides the MIME type of the file but this information is [provided by the browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). As such:

> This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore
>   don't take its value for granted.

However, it's worth nothing that the `$_FILES` superglobal is by no means read-only. Like other superglobals, your PHP code can overwrite it:

```
$_FILES['file']['type'] = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
```

Assuming that you aren't fiddling with `$_FILES`, the first obvious troubleshooting step is to fire your browser's debugger tools and inspect the POST data it sends. If that's the source of the string, you can forget about PHP.

I don't know what your browser is. In Google Chrome (in other browsers similar instructions apply) you must open the upload form, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and then click on "Network":

[image: Chrome - Network]

When you pick a file and submit the form, you'll see the request:

[image: Chrome - Submit]

Expand the node and you'll see the data (`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` in this case):

[image: Chrome - Payload]

This MIME type is normally configured by the Microsoft Office installer. If yours contains `/folder/files/report/april_2013.xlsx` you might need to repair or reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Just totally wrong file? Name: report.xlsx
And after that youn say april_2013.xlsx like @h2ooooooo said.

I think you just copied the code from another file.